# Add Right-Click Save as PDF in Windows Explorer

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, conversion, autohotkey, context-menu

I'm looking for a way to be able to add some options to the Right Click Context menu in Windows 7. I really don't have much experience in programming much but I am very eager and willing to learn.

Specifically I'd like to be able to Right Click a word document and have it convert or save as a .PDF file. I want to be able to convert existing documents into PDF format. The documents are 99% of the time going to be Microsoft Word documents so if there is a way to automate that, guidance there is appreciated.

I'm aware there are other methods of doing this such as downloading a "PDF Printer" but I would rather avoid that method if I could. I would also like to avoid downloading more software to install on user's PC's if possible as well.

Hopefully I am not being very demanding but I really do appreciate any help or guidance you can offer.

(As a Bonus I'd like to see if I can also get the option to Saves as PDF and Send as an attachment if possible.)

Comment: Office 2010 allows you to save as a PDF. What version of office are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for forgetting about this question but at least I am finally answering the question, right?

I could not find a way to accomplish this the way I wanted so I did a slight workaround. I created and compiled 2 separate .ahk ([AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)) scripts and added them to the right click context menus.

Here are the scripts:

### Convert .DOC and .DOCX to PDF (Requires Office 2007 or 2010)

```
; AutoHotkey Script by Cyborg v1.5

; This script is designed to be compiled and ran in the user's Send To Right-Click Menu.
; The user needs to right click a word document go into the send to menu and choose this
; script. After launching the script the selected file will open in its version of Word
; and open the menus to save it as a PDF. In this version the user is unable to rename the
; the file.

; NOTE: In order for this to work correctly with Office 2007 you MUST have already installed
; the PDF/XPS converter from Microsoft.

SetTitleMatchMode 2

Loop %0%
{
Path := %A_Index%
Run,% Path
}

IfWinExist, Microsoft Word
    WinActivate

sleep 1000

Word2007:
IfExist, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE ; Microsoft Word 2007
{
    Send ^s
    Send !f
    Send f
    Send p
    Sleep 500
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 500
    WinClose, Microsoft Word
}
else
{
    Goto, Word2010
}
return

Word2010:
IfExist, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE ; Microsoft Word 2010
{
    Send ^s
    Send !f
    Send d
    Send p
    Send a
    Sleep 500
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 500
    WinClose, Microsoft Word
}
else
{
    Goto, Word2013
}
return
```

### Convert .XLS and .XLSX to PDF (Requires Office 2007 or 2010)

```
; AutoHotkey Script by Cyborg v1.5

; This script is designed to be compiled and ran in the user's Send To Right-Click Menu.
; The user needs to right click a word document go into the send to menu and choose this
; script. After launching the script the selected file will open in its version of Excel
; and open the menus to save it as a PDF. In this version the user is unable to rename the
; the file.

; NOTE: In order for this to work correctly with Office 2007 you MUST have already installed
; the PDF/XPS converter from Microsoft.

SetTitleMatchMode 2

Loop %0%
{
Path := %A_Index%
Run,% Path
}

IfWinExist, Microsoft Excel
    WinActivate

sleep 1500

Excel2007:
IfExist, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE ; Microsoft Excel 2007
{
    Send ^s
    Send !f
    Send f
    Send p
    Sleep 700
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 700
    WinClose, Microsoft Excel
}
else
{
    Goto, Excel2010
}
return

Excel2010:
IfExist, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE ; Microsoft Excel 2010
{
    Send ^s
    Send !f
    Send d
    Send p
    Send a
    Sleep 500
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 500
    WinClose, Microsoft Excel
}
else
{
    Goto, Excel2013
}
return

Excel2013:
    MsgBox, Excel 2013 Not Configured for this Script.
return
```

Once I wrote these scripts and compiled them into .exes I placed them into the SendTo by [following this guide by HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/).

You may also be able to apply each script to each filetype but I didn't look into that.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution for Word 2013. It involves only adding a Visual Basic macro to Word and few records to the registry.

Create a global macro in Word 2013: open any document in Word, open the built-in Visual Basic editor (Alt + F11), select **Normal** in the left panel, click *Insert* in the main menu, then *Module*, and copy the code into the editor:

```
Sub ExportToPDFext()
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory ThisDocument.Path
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".")) + "pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, _
        OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, _
        KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
        DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
        UseISO19005_1:=False
    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Save the module (Ctrl + S) and close Visual Basic editor and Word.

Then add the context menu options to registry. Create and execute a file with the extension `.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\SavePDFhere]
@="Save PDF here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\SavePDFhere\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.EXE\" /mExportToPDFext /q \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\SavePDFhere]
@="Save PDF here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\SavePDFhere\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.EXE\" /mExportToPDFext /q \"%1\""
```

The right-click "Save PDF here" will appear in Explorer for DOC and DOCX files.

It works silently and supports batch conversion of several selected documents.

Comment: Oleksiy, does this work with Word 2010 by a chance?

Comment: saulius2, unfortunately I don't have Word 2010 to check.

Comment: I've checked this thing with Office 2010 a few days later.  It works here too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use the command line ability of [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/download)  to convert any printable file to PDF

1. Download and install PDFCreator together with its [COM  module](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/com-interface). The COM module is important or else the following VBscript can not comunicate with your PDF printer
2. Copy & paste this code to a text file and save it as `Convert2PDF.vbs`

   ```
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set PDFCreator = Wscript.CreateObject("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator", "PDFCreator_")

   With PDFCreator
    ReadyState = 0
    .cStart "/NoProcessingAtStartup"
    .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1
    .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
    .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0
    .cOption("AutosaveStartStandardProgram") = 0
    DefaultPrinter = .cDefaultprinter
    .cDefaultprinter = "PDFCreator"
    .cClearcache
    .cPrinterStop = false
    .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.Arguments(0))
    .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = fso.GetBaseName(WScript.Arguments(0))
    .cPrintfile cStr(WScript.Arguments(0))
     c = 0
     Do While (ReadyState = 0) and (c < 120)
      c = c + 1
      Wscript.Sleep 250
     Loop
    .cDefaultprinter = DefaultPrinter
    .cClearcache
    WScript.Sleep 200
    .cClose
   End With

   Public Sub PDFCreator_eReady()
    ReadyState = 1
   End Sub
   ```
3. Place a shortcut to your VBscript in your shell:sendto folder for faster access

   [image]

   *(or)*

   Execute your VBScript from the command line if you want full control over the output file name.
   Use this [slightly changed code for this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8cc0e5c6bc316b3ccd1).

   ```
    C:\Convert2PDF.vbs "C:\inputfile.doc" "C:\outputfolder" "outputfilename"
   ```

Comment: Nice one.  But I found PDCreator sometimes crashing inside the script.  In such case it leaves default printer unrestored which is a pain for casual user.

It probably would suffice to add few VBA statements for catching exceptions, but finally I chose using plain MS Office 2010:( since it works more realiably.