# Windows 7 batch command-line to save as .pdf file for word 2013 .docx file

Tags: command-line, pdf, batch, batch-file, microsoft-word-2013

I'd like to have the fastest way to export my report *.docx* file to *.pdf* and distribute it to others whenever I've got a new, updated version.

I'm looking for a command-line approach that automates the following steps that I have to do manually using my mouse so far:

```
File -> Save as -> Browse for location
```

What are my command options for a batch file?

Comment: Check out this question: http://superuser.com/questions/541357/add-right-click-save-as-pdf-in-windows-explorer

Answer (score 12):

Create a global macro in Word 2013:

```
' The Word macro for exporting to PDF (the Word window closes after finishing)
Sub ExportToPDFext()
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory ThisDocument.Path
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".")) + "pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, _
        OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, _
        KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
        DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
        UseISO19005_1:=False
    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

After that you can convert a Word document to PDF in command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" /mExportToPDFext /q "your_document_path.docx"
```

The Word window will not even show up because it's set to closing after the macro finishes working, and the parameter /q disables the splash window when Word is loading.

Here are the alternative detailed instructions [on GitHub](https://github.com/oleksiykovtun/Word-Export-to-PDF). Also, the context menu option allows batch converting even without the command line. It can be added to registry. For DOC and DOCX:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\SavePDFhere]
@="Save PDF here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\SavePDFhere\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.EXE\" /mExportToPDFext /q \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\SavePDFhere]
@="Save PDF here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\SavePDFhere\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.EXE\" /mExportToPDFext /q \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 3):

For a simple command-line tool to batch convert you can use, `docx2pdf`: https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf/

Install:

```
pip install docx2pdf
```

Run:

```
docx2pdf myFolderOfWordDocs
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool.

Comment: Easy to install and use; this tool certainly helped me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution from [Oleksiy Kovtun](https://superuser.com/users/398624/oleksiy-kovtun) adopted to the current Office 16 (Office 360).

In the Word macro I had to change `ThisDocument.Path` to `ActiveDocument.Path`.

```vb
' The Word macro for exporting to PDF (the Word window closes after finishing)
Sub ExportToPDFext()
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory ActiveDocument.Path
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".")) + "pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, _
        OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, _
        KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
        DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
        UseISO19005_1:=False
    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

For the registry Office 16 uses a slightly different paths:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\SavePDFhere]
@="Save PDF here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\SavePDFhere\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE\" /mExportToPDFext /q \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\SavePDFhere]
@="Save PDF here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\SavePDFhere\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE\" /mExportToPDFext /q \"%1\""
```