# Converting Multiple .doc files to searchable .pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, batch, macros, ocr

I have a batch command file that runs daily converting data extract files to .txt, .doc, and then to .pdf formats. I run a series of formatting macros in Word on the .txt file before saving to .doc file. Then I run the following macro found here:

[Windows 7 batch command-line to save as .pdf file for word 2013 .docx file](https://superuser.com/questions/789968/windows-7-batch-command-line-to-save-as-pdf-file-for-word-2013-docx-file/852180#852180?newreg=80caff1607ed4cc2bc338551ffb80f23)

```
' The Word macro for exporting to PDF (the Word window closes after finishing)
Sub ExportToPDFext()
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory ThisDocument.Path
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".")) + "pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, _
        OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, _
        KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
        DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
        UseISO19005_1:=False
    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

The problem that I am having is that unlike the MS Word 2010 "Save as PDF" functionality, this macro does not seem to keep the PDF saved in a OCR searchable format.

Any advice on how to improve this macro or add the OCR segment in the batch file? I would prefer not to have to download and install additional software to perform this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, when taking 1 file and recording a Save As PDF macro then running that simplified macro, the output file is OCR searchable. But when running this macro for all files within a folder, the output is not OCR searchable. The only real differences is the 'changefileopendirectory', 'OutputFileName', and the 'application.quit' coding. I'm stumped why it is acting differently.